# How to install google.cloud with Python pip?

Tags: python, pip, google-cloud-vision

I am relatively new to Python and I am stuck on something which is probably relatively easy to resolve.

I have installed the following packages:

```
pip install --upgrade google-api-python-client
pip install --upgrade google-cloud
pip install --upgrade google-cloud-vision
```

In my Python file I have:

```
import cv2
import io
import os

# Imports the Google Cloud client library
from google.cloud import vision

...etc...
```

And this gives me the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 6, in <module>
    from google.cloud import vision
ImportError: No module named 'google.cloud'
```

What am I missing and where should I look (logs?) to find the answer in the future.

PS:
Pip installs of `google-cloud` and `google-cloud-vision` have the output:

```
Cannot remove entries from nonexistent file /Users/foobar/anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/easy-install.pth
```

**UPDATE**:
Running `pip freeze` doesn't show the packages to be installed...

Comment: The above worked for me on both Windows and Ubuntu (using Python 3.5). Try again in a fresh conda environment perhaps?

Comment: Hmm, nope, that doesn't do the trick either...

Comment: Also updated the question...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had a similar problem. Adding "--ignore-installed" to my pip command made it work for me.

This might be a bug in pip - see this page for more details: https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/2751

Answer (score 1):

You need to download and install the google-cloud-sdk. Follow this link https://cloud.google.com/sdk/docs/

Answer (score -7):

try this :

```
from google.cloud.vision import *
```